# SQL count each distinct value in column and add name from another table where the ID matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

My SQL Skills are next to none. After looking around for the past 2 hours trying to figure this out I need some help please.

I have 2 tables as below

```
Table1                    Table2 

ID  | Name                Status_id
-----------               ----------
1   |   Open                  1
2   |   Closed                2
3   |   On-Hold               1
```

What I would like to do is count the status_id in table 2 and group by the status_id.  Then add the Name where the ID matches in the first column.

What I have at the moment is

```
SELECT status_id, COUNT(*) AS 'num' FROM table2 GROUP BY status_id
```

This is great so far and returns

```
1   |   2
2   |   1
```

What I need to return is

```
Open   |   2
Closed |   1
```

I hope that is clear.  Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON b.status_id=a.id 
GROUP BY status_id
```

Comment: Fantastic, easy when you know how!  Thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: There is also a column in table2 called "date".  Do you know how I could specify this data to only show if that date is equal to today?  The date is currently stored as "1341241153". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you want to also have Zero for On-Hold you'd need to do a LEFT join and count the a column from table2 instead of `*`

```
SELECT t1.name,
       Count(t2.Status_id) AS num 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
               ON t1.id = t2.Status_id
GROUP  BY t1.name;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f51/6)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I think I prefer it not to show anything that does not have a value.  It makes the chart I am doing less confusing. There is also a column in table2 called "date". Do you know how I could specify this data to only show if that date is equal to today? The date is currently stored as "1341241153". Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should really put that in another question since a) pretty much I'm the only one that's going to read your question and b) its hard for people to find the answer that buried in a comment.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by "show". This could mean only show the value in the column when its today or only show the rows if its today.

Comment: Sure no problem.  I will add it to another question and make myself clearer.  Thanks